# Is there a clear Ollydbg successor?

Tags: ida, ollydbg, ghidra, x64dbg

I used Ollydbg 2.01 back in 2014 when Olly was working to create a 64-bit version.  I was very eager to see the 64-bit version, but sadly that never came to pass.  I abandoned reverse engineering for a while, but now I would like to pick it up again and continue learning.  So my question to the experts is whether there is a 64-bit successor to the 32-bit Ollydbg.

Alternatively, what tools do you all use to reverse engineer 64-bit programs?

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. This is a question eliciting an opinion, something that isn't appropriate for this Q&A site. However by tagging you pretty much [gave the answer yourself](https://x64dbg.com/), even if you perhaps did it unknowingly. By and large x64dbg is what I'd consider a successor to OllyDbg. On the other hand, other folks may have a different opinion. You could also give WinDbgX (available as "WinDbg Preview" in Windows Store) a try.

Comment: Additionally, I think widening the scope of your question in the last paragraph isn't exactly helping. Debuggers are for dynamic analysis, other tools exist for static analysis. Both are ways to reverse engineer code.